# Is there a way to just store the time in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I thought the Time object in Ruby on Rails stores the time but when I ran `Time.now.beginning_of_day` it gives me the date as well.  I'm just trying to capture the time and not the date at all.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with that time?  Display it as a string?  Use it in calculations as an integer?  Will that be local time or GMT?  Time without a date can be useless (think "daylight savings in effect -- or maybe not?")

Comment: I run to run calculations on when a store is open or not mainly.  Display is not the main thing I'm trying to solve here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to do Rails Date Formats – strftime

please see this kink http://www.wetware.co.nz/2009/07/rails-date-formats-strftime/

and this link http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Example: 
    // in your case, should do it
    Time.now.beginning_of_day.strftime("%I:%M")

```
With preceding zero (capital I)

Time.now.strftime("%I:%M") # => 05:21
Without preceding zero (lowercase L)

Time.now.strftime("%l:%M") # => 5:21
```

hope it help.

`UPDATE`: // well for your question on the comment below `Why is Time storing date information? Shouldn't it just be time?`

Good point for you question, as `vladr` mention it above(`I am sure that the group of people who create rails will think very similar to vladr mention above when they gonna design Time object in rail`), when you are talking about time, it cannot be help that it will related to the time zone too. In your case you want to use Time.now.beginning_of_day right? I am now in Thailand and assume that you are in America, Time in America is slower than Thailand for 12 hours, so right now in Thailand it's Tue 10:00 am, then in America should be  Mon 10:00 pm, so you use Time.now.beginning_of_day (let use Time.now for more clear picture), so what should be the answer? so that's why I think the group of people who create rails use UTC+0 as a standard, In your case I recommend using Time.zone.now, and recently I have found some blog with interesting topic, please see http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails, hope it help. anyone who read this if you feel that something is missing, feel free to edit my answer, thank you very much for you guys :).

Comment: Why is Time storing date information? Shouldn't it just be time?

Comment: I update the answer already, please see and if you have any question please feel free too tell me, I will try my best, Stack overflow is use for share knowledge anyway :) Long live stack overflow!!